# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed even with the same id

Tags: mysql

Table registered users;

```
CREATE TABLE `registeredusers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`UserName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ResetPassword` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`friends` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table updates:

```
 CREATE TABLE `updates` (
 `update_id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `update` VARCHAR(45),
 `user_id_fk` VARCHAR(45),
 `created` INT(11) ,
 `ip` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id_fk) REFERENCES registeredusers(id));
```

I am following a tutorial here http://www.9lessons.info/2014/03/facebook-style-friend-request-system.html

I already have a table `registeredusers` and I am trying the sql code provided in the tutorial with the existing table and I keep getting this error Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed, though I have created a table named `friends` with the same reference to the registeredusers table and it works perfectly.

Comment: It's a bit strange that the foreign key and the field it references are of different types. I can see that's how it is in that blog post... but that doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The column being referred is not of same datatype as the the foreign key:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

vs:

```
`user_id_fk` VARCHAR(45),
```

Those two need to be of the same datatype. Change second definition to:

```
 CREATE TABLE `updates` (
 `update_id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `update` VARCHAR(45),
 `user_id_fk` int(11),   -- here
 `created` INT(11) ,
 `ip` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id_fk) REFERENCES registeredusers(id));
```